# Overlap between two kernel densities in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, reclassify, kernel-density

I have two different kernel reclassified raster files and I would like to find the overlap area between them, what I should do?

I have tried Boolean operators and map algebra and it does not work.

Comment: What excactly did you try, as map algebra should work?

Comment: What bit depth are your raster data in (e.g. 8 bit unsigned, float, etc). Does this answer your question?: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/25889/8104

Comment: Hi all! First, thank you for your reply! Sir Matte, I tried the following I used one kernel reclassified file of plant species Selaginella apoda and I used one second kernel reclassified file of plant species S. arenicola. In map algebra, I used i.e. + or * and as extent the intersection of inputs.  This is not work as I want. The overlapping area should be an area with the common values between them, not all the area. As we know Intersect tool it works only for features as I did between Minimum Boundaries Geometries of two species. Also, Sir Aaron, my bit depth is 8 bit and integer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you just want to identify areas of overlap, try 'Extract by Mask'

If you want to identify areas of similar density, use 'Raster Calculator' to subtract one dataset from the other and decide on a threshold to define similar, then use 'Raster Calculator' to execute a conditional, e.g.:

```
Con(("raster" < 1) | ("raster" > -1), 1, 0)
```