# Intersection solution in Rasters

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.5

I have two rasters: one is building footprint (BF) having 3 classes, another raster is landslide hazard zones (LHZ), also having 3 classes. I have prepared matrix where the intersection of each of the classes from BF with those from LHZ should have separate new output classes. Could you provide solutions how to perform this exercise in ArcGIS 10.5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding intersection of two rasters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25889/finding-intersection-of-two-rasters)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the three classes in each raster are labeled 1,2 and 3. Using the raster calculator, create your intersection matrix as BF + 10 * LHZ, which will have 9 distinct values  - 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, ..., 33.

Comment: thanks alot for your suggestions...